# How to reference a property from a different class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reference

I have a class with a list of objects of the type of a different class. Now I´d like to build a function that iterates over this list and for each object then iterates over a list defined in the type class.

Here´s the code for the class I´m working in:

```
class Zoo {

    var tiere = mutableListOf<Animal>()

    fun getTotalAdoptionMoney(): Double {
        var totalMoney = 0.0
        for (t in tiere) {
            //TODO how to get list of adoptionen from Animal?
            for (a in adoptionen) {
                totalMoney += a.price
            }
        }
        return totalMoney
    }
```

And here is the code for the type class:

```
abstract class Animal (val species : String , val age : Int ): Adoption{
    open fun makeSound () : String {return ""}
    open var adoptionen = mutableListOf<Adoption>()
```

I´ve tried quite a few things, but nothing has worked. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can write `t.adoptionen` to access the property `adoptionen` of an `Animal` `t`.